# How can I create a Dynamic Route in Flask from an existing View?

Tags: python, flask

I am somewhat stuck trying to figure out how to configure a route in Flask properly. I'll try and give some contextual information first:

My web app allows **Users** to join **Clubs**. A user can join 1 or many **clubs**.

Each **Club** has a dashboard page, and I am serving that to the user via Blueprint:

Route:

```
@club_bp.route("/clubdashboard/<int:Club_id>", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def clubdashboard(Club_id):
    """Logged-in User Club Dashboard."""
    selectedClub=Club.query.get(Club_id)
    
    return render_template(
        "clubdashboard.html",
        title="Club Dashboard",
        current_user=current_user,
        clubname=selectedClub.name,
        members = selectedClub.members
    )
```

Jinja2 Template Snippet:

```
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            {% for club in current_user.users %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('club_bp.clubdashboard', Club_id=club.id) }}">{{ club.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

The **currentuser.users** property contains a **List** of id values for clubs the user is a member of (the .users property is crappy naming on my part, it's on my todo list to fix it.)

The Jinja snippet creates a dropdown menu in the navbar to allow the **clubdashboard** route to serve an individual dashboard per club.

What I am looking to do is within the **Club Dashboard** view have a link called "**Customize**" that, in future, can do a bunch of things (not exactly relevant just yet), but first i'd like to just figure out how to serve the page properly.

For any individual club dashboard I get a URL such as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/clubdashboard/763074009760399361
```

What i'd like is simply to serve a URL like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/clubdashboard/763074009760399361/customize
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any ideas on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the route:

```py
@club_bp.route("/clubdashboard/<int:club_id>/customize", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def club_customize(club_id):
    """Customize whatever is specific to your club"""
    return "TODO: Actually make it work"
```

And then you can route to it with a simple `url_for("club_bp.club_customize", club_id=club.id)`

In order to have access to the club ID in `clubdashboard.html` you need to pass in either the selected club or the club ID in your `clubdashboard` function:

```py
def clubdashboard(Club_id):
    """Logged-in User Club Dashboard."""
    selectedClub=Club.query.get(Club_id)
    
    return render_template(
        "clubdashboard.html",
        title = "Club Dashboard",
        current_user = current_user,
        clubname = selectedClub.name,
        club = selectedClub,  # <-- This lets `club.id` work in the template
        members = selectedClub.members
    )
```

Comment: The issue I would have with doing it this way is how to get the correct club id to pass into the route function. Does the flask session remember the club object that is loaded through the parent route?

Comment: You don't want to pass it in the session, instead pass it in the parameters you pass to your Jinja2 template in `clubdashboard`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working how i'd like. Not sure if it's exactly the best way to do it so happy to be corrected still, but here goes:

In my existing Dashboard route, I took the club ID value and stored it in a user session variable:

```
    @club_bp.route("/clubdashboard/<int:Club_id>", methods=["GET"])
    @login_required
    def clubdashboard(Club_id):
        """Logged-in User Club Dashboard."""
        selectedClub=Club.query.get(Club_id)
        session['selectedclubid'] = selectedClub.id
    
        return render_template(
            "clubdashboard.html",
            title="Club Dashboard",
            current_user=current_user,
            clubname=selectedClub.name,
            members = selectedClub.members
        )
```

I then pass the session variable into the Club Rules (Customise) route from the Jinja template:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('club_bp.rules', Club_id=session['selectedclubid']) }}">Club Rules</a>
```

Route:

```
    @club_bp.route("/clubdashboard/<int:Club_id>/rules", methods=["GET"])
    @login_required
    def rules(Club_id):
        """Logged-in User Club Dashboard."""
        selectedClub=Club.query.get(Club_id)
        
        return render_template(
            "clubrules.html",
            title="Club Rules",
            current_user=current_user,
            clubname=selectedClub.name,
            members = selectedClub.members
        )
```

This route performs a query for the relevant data and displays. I might have been overthinking the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't pass this in the session.  If a user opens two tabs and navigates to two different clubs (first Club A then Club B) and then clicks on the "customize" dashboard for "Club A" they will see the "customize" dashboard for Club B (because the session variable was reset when they navigated to Club B).  Instead pass the data to the template via another template parameter.